# ggplot2: How do I colorize elements of a table within a plotarea?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, annotate

I made a bar plot with ggplot2 that contains a data table within its plot area. How can I colorize text elements within this data table?

I know how to colorize text with "geom_richtext", but how is it done in a data table ?

The example below draws the bar plot, a data table within the area, and text (where colors can be applied). But how can they be applied to table elements (e.g. to the words within table cells)?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
library(ggpmisc)
library(ggpp)

data = data.frame(
  colors = c('black, red, black again', 'green, yello, now blue'), 
  x = c(1, 2),
  y = c(5, 10))

gg = ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
     geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = 'blue')

gg = gg +
     annotate(geom = 'table', x = 1, y = 7, label = list(data), parse = F) 

mytext = glue::glue("black, <span style = \'color: red;\'>red</span>, black again ....")

gg = gg +
     geom_richtext(aes(x = 1.5, y = 3, label = mytext), label.color = NA)

gg
```

Comment: `geom_table` does not use rich text. Its drawing method uses `gridExtra::tableGrob`, which _could_ use rich text with a lot of cajoling, but `geom_table` is hard coded to use a text grob rather than a rich text grob. If this is very important to you, then the solution is to build the table yourself out of `geom_tile` or `geom_rect` layers and add the text via `geom_richtext`. (It would also be possible, but even more convoluted, to add a tableGrob that uses richtext as a custom annotation. This seems like too much work for the end result)

Comment: Is it really necessary to use ggplot for that? In the alike case I shifted to `flextable` allowing you to set backgrounds and of other rich text attributes with rendering of this output afterwards.

Comment: ....flextable .. that's an interesting thought ... did you combine it with a plot?